# Possible error in the Android docs code example or am I missing something?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I was looking into how to create a multichoice checkbox dialog while working in Android Studio and naturally started by looking at the android developers page and came across [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#Checkboxes). The code example they show is this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    selectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_toppings)
    // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
    // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
           .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.toppings, null,
                      new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                       boolean isChecked) {
                   if (isChecked) {
                       // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                       selectedItems.add(which);
                   } else if (selectedItems.contains(which)) {
                       // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                       selectedItems.remove(which);
                   }
               }
           })
    // Set the action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User clicked OK, so save the selectedItems results somewhere
                   // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
                   ...
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   ...
               }
           });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Now what Im interested in looking at is this:

```
.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.toppings, null,
                      new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                       boolean isChecked) {
                   if (isChecked) {
                       // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                       selectedItems.add(which);
                   } else if (selectedItems.contains(which)) {
                       // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                       selectedItems.remove(which);
                   }
               }
           })
```

Now I am missing something here or is there a mistake in the code here? What I mean is wouldn't the call to `remove()` in `selectedItems.remove(which)` interpret `which` as an `int` rather than an `Object` and thus remove the element at the position specified by the `int` stored in `which` rather than removing the actual `int` from the array? This is what I assumed would happen when I read the code and also what did happen for me when I tried to run the code leading to an `IndexOutOfBoundsError`.

However as the code comes from a resource that Google itself provides I feel like its likely that it must be me that is missing something. If that is the case what am I missing? If that isn't the case and there is in fact an error in the code then I apologise as the topic no longer seems relevant for stackoverflow.

When it comes to how to solve the issue Im encountering that isn't an issue as I realise that I can simply do something like `selectedItems.remove((Integer) which)` or `selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which))`. I am simply bewildered as to what is happening.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: It does look like a mistake and considering that the app also throws an error, you have verified it. Your proposed solution should work. Probably just human error since `int` gets auto-boxed normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagnosis is correct.  Given two overloads `List.remove(int)` and `List.remove(Object)` and a call with an `int` argument, the Java compiler will statically resolve the call to the first overload rather than the second one<sup>1</sup>.  But the semantics of this context require the second overload; i.e. removal by value rather than by position.

It's a bug in the documentation.  Report it through the normal channels ...

---

<sup>1 - This is specified in [JLS 15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).  This part of the spec is complicated and technical, but the gist is that the compiler first looks for overloads that match the argument types *strictly*; i.e. without boxing or unboxing.  It only considers non-strict matches if there are no strict ones.  Informally, `int` -> `int` is a "closer match" than `int` -> `Object` which involves boxing to `Integer` followed by reference widening to `Object`.</sup>